# How to insert data into temp tables from a stored procedure which returns two select queries data

Tags: t-sql

I have a stored Procedure which will return two sets of data without any condition, I want to store that returned data in two temp tables.
Here's an example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

AS
BEGIN
    --  ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.       
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * FROM table1        
    SELECT * FROM table2
END
GO
```

create procedure sp2

exec sp1 ---want to store result of table1 into temp1 and table2 into temp2

Comment: Which part of it are you stuck on?

Comment: retrieving in some other store procedure

Comment: I suppose you can use global temporary tables to store the data for access by another SP. Take a look at this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELECT ... INTO as follows:

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable1 FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is the SELECT INTO statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureName
AS
SELECT * 
INTO #tempTable1
FROM Table1

SELECT * 
INTO #tempTable2
FROM Table2
```

If there are parameters that need to be used just place them in the WHERE clause for their respective Tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use an optional parameter to the stored proc that makes it return only one dataset at a time. To return all the datasets as normal, simply omit the parameter when calling the sproc.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp1 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ResultSet int = null
AS
BEGIN
    --  ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.       
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    if (@ResultSet is null or @ResultSet = 1)
        SELECT * FROM table1

    if (@ResultSet is null or @ResultSet = 2)
        SELECT * FROM table2
END
GO
```

The downside here of course is your stored proc must be idempotent as you'll have to call it multiple times.